# TX.wait() never resolves even though transaction has already been completed

Tags: ether, ethers.js, hardhat

I am using ethers.js 6.2 and hardhat to test my code.

```
const swapTx =  await routerContract.swapExactETHForTokens(
    amountOutMin,
    [WETH, token_address],
    ME,
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10,
    {'value': ETHAmountIn,"gasPrice": gasPrice, "gasLimit": gasLimit}
)
//console.log(swapTx);
let receipt = await swapTx.wait();
```

When I run this code, hardhat shows the transaction has already been completed. And in the wallet, I can see the swap has happed correctly.

```
eth_sendRawTransaction
  Contract call:   <UnrecognizedContract>
  Transaction:     0x499d04cf2afef112c1715b7821131873a2e5475080ad20f262dda9a65b5c9864
  From:            0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:              0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d
  Value:           1 ETH
  Gas used:        157884 of 221283
  Block #17664625: 0x8d2d257060ec0bc0b0a8fbf71a1bc2cb99eaabbf6d0a2c27f8bb0b7909db99af

eth_chainId (2)
eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_chainId
eth_subscribe
```

This is what routerContract looks like to see the function doing the swap.

```
const routerContract = new hre.ethers.Contract(
    router,
    [
        'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
    ],
    signer
);
```

I have already tried increasing gas and tried getting the receipt through the provider like... But I am still unable to get the receipt

```
let reciept = await provider.waitForTransaction(swapTx.hash, 1)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `v6.8.1`. Looking at the RPC geth console, I see the tx is sent and processed by the RPC node, but examining the miner node, the tx is never mined. `txpool.status` in RPC geth console shows the tx is pending ...

If I use the non-hardhat ethers (same version) and setup the `JsonRpcProvider` manually (with the same exact values), everything works as expected. It seems that hardhat flavor of ethers is sending the tx incorrectly so that it never gets picked up by the miner.